# Slice array using other array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of the same length that contain elements from 0 to 1. For example:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.random.permutation(x)
```

I grouped the elements of x in bins of width 0.1:

```
bins = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
x_bin = []
for i in range(1,10):
    x_bin.append(x[np.digitize(x,bins)==i])
```

Now I would like to slice y in groups which have the same lengths of the arrays in x_bin.

How can I do that?

A possible way is:

```
y0 = y[0:len(x_bin[0])]
```

and so on, but it is not very elegant.

Comment: if all arrays are of equal length, ```y.reshape(x_bin[0].shape[0], -1)```

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want to use as a more elegant solution than using loops:

```
l = [len(x) for x in x_bin]  # get bin lengths
split_indices = np.cumsum(l)  # sum up lengths for correct split indices
y_split = np.split(y, split_indices)
```

I got the array lengths via list comprehension and then splitted the np array using the gathered indices. This can be shortened to a single python instruction, but it is much easier to read this way.

Comment: `np.split` hides another iteration.  So your solution has two python level loops (plus a compiled one in the `cumsum`.

Answer (score 0):

> A possible way is:
>
> `y0 = y[0:len(x_bin[0])]`
>
> and so on, but it is not very elegant.

instead of using `y0 = ...` `y1 = ...` you can make a list of slices:

```
slices = []
for n in len(y):
    slices.append(y[n:len(x_bin[0])])
```

(this might be wrong, but the principle is there)

instead of haveing `y0` `y1` and so on, you will have `slices[0]`, `slices[1]` and so on